# Links inside of larger clickable areas (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css, nested, hyperlink

Here's a good article on creating links inside of larger clickable areas:

http://css-tricks.com/links-inside-of-larger-clickable-areas/

This solution requires JavaScript. At the end of the article, there's a broken link to a CSS-only solution (so apparently it can be done), but I can't figure out how this would be done with CSS only. Any ideas?

[image: Links inside larger clickable area]

Comment: So each of the red areas are clickable? As is the big green area?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Of course, you could just slice the large green area into two halves so that they are separate but flow together visually, but then if you want to had a :hover effect to the green area, you're out of luck without JavaScript...

Comment: @danielfaraday - I think slicing is the right solution here. Having adjacent clickable areas with no gap can lead to confusing misclicks. The styling issue you mention can be got around, see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't seem too difficult to me ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztZun/1/)).

HTML:

```
<header>
    <a href="#1">Clickable</a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#2">Clickable</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#3">Clickable</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#4">Clickable</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#5">Clickable</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
​
```

CSS:

```
a { color: #f4ebd4; font-family: sans-serif; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 0.8em; }

header { text-align: center; }

header > a { display: block;  line-height: 100px; }

header > a, header > a + nav { background: #4b885c; }
a:hover, a:hover + nav { background: blue; }

nav ul { display: table; width: 100%; }
nav li { display: table-cell; }
nav a { display: block; background: #a51d2c; padding: 10px 20px; margin: 10px; }
​
```

Comment: Wow, the markup is valid too! The key is setting `line-height: 100%` on the 'outer' link. Very cool.

Comment: well no, that's just one simple way to center one line of text in its parent block (it wouldn't work with 2 lines of text for example). If that's all you're worried about then it's the `display: block` on the top link that's important - after that you can do what you want with the link to size it how you want

Comment: Ah, note that it was `line-height: 100px`, *not* `100%` - that may have confused you.

Comment: This doesn't work any more (in Chrome at least). Clicking any of the smaller link triggers the larger green area link

Comment: @DavidBall I don't see how that's possible - there's no overlap between the clickable areas. Are you sure you don't have any Javascript or other complications going on?

Comment: How can this be valid markup, if the [W3C `<a>` specification (HTML5)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) explicitly forbids *interactive content* (which apparently the `<a>` element belongs to) for `<a>` elements??

Comment: @Neon - because there aren't any `<a>`s that are children of other `<a>`s in my markup. Note that in my Fiddle, the bottom part of the green area isn't clickable - as I mentioned in a comment above, having clickable areas without any gap in-between can be confusing for UX

Comment: @Gareth Didn't see that somehow. That's bad. I was actually happy about it. Now I need to look for another solution. In my case I need the areas between the red buttons to belong to the big link as well. A bummer. Probably JS or absolute positioning...

Answer (score 2):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/5MkVW/ I quickly put it together in the last 5 mins at work, might be a bit messy but have a go.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize nested `<a>` tags would work. (The syntax is illegal of course, but it seems to work). I cleaned up your JSFiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/7bP2T/

Comment: Updated with real links: http://jsfiddle.net/XdtN2/. Tested working in IE9 (despite invalid HTML).