# link within a link?

Tags: html, iframe

i'm using an `iframe` within my html, loading an image gallery i found from the web. Each `img` has an information bar you can click on, and when the bar opens it provides viewers with additional info.

```
<a href="images/test.jpg">
        <img src="images/test.jpg", 
         data-big=""
         data-title="test title"
         data-description="test description"/>
    </a>
```

i would like to insert another link in the `data-description` element that sits within a linked image, but i don't know if this is possible and if so, how?

Comment: what plugin are you using?

Comment: Actually, there's an attribute designed specifically for such cases: [*longdesc*](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img/longdesc). But as its support is close to zero, one has to implement the necessary functionality in JS.

Comment: What does the loop look like for creating the gallery? It could be as simple as just adding a line to append or insertAfter.

Comment: data-description is an attribute of an element, not an element. You'll want to remove the comma from the img tag.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/4YPvp/

```
.link {
    position: relative;
}
.link span {
    position: absolute;
}

<a class="link" href="http://cnn.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" data-big="" data-title="test title" data-description="test description"/>
    <span data-url="http://npr.org">Other link</span>
</a>

$('.link span').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('data-url');
});
```

Note that I used jQuery for this example.

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not allow the nesting of links, although you can hook up a JavaScript-based click handler that changes the behaviour of the link.

More details are needed to answer your question fully.