# How to put a tag inside data-description

Tags: html

I have a'a' tag, something like this:

```
<a href="..." data-title="..." data-description="..."></a>
```

How can i put a link inside the `data-description` tag, so that i have a link inside a description link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest tags inside of tag attributes.

You can refer to this: [Link inside a div link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437785/link-inside-a-div-link)

Comment: Attributes as such are just data, and the link refers to a question about nesting links, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a tag there, e.g.

```
<a href="..." data-title="..." data-description="foo <b>bar</b>">...</a>
```

The value of an attribute is parsed as plain text, except for character/entity references, so the less than character `<` is just another data character.

Nothing inside a `data-*` attribute value is parsed as a tag, but that’s a special case of the fact that it is unspecified text. *All* use of such attributes is by definition dependent on what you do in your page or application. So if you need something to be interpreted as tags, just write the processing so that they will be so interpreted.