# dropdown isn't appearing on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, dropdown

I've written very primitive navbar. By reading code everything seems logical and correct but code doesn't work - when you move cursor over "News" bar the dropdown menu doesn't appear. What am I missing?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Learning</title>
<style>
 body{
  margin: 0px;}

 body a {
  display: inline-block;
  width:25%;
  padding: 14px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;}

 .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
  color: white;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 25%;}

 .dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;}

 a.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
  display: block;}

 body > a:hover, .dropdown-content a:hover{
  background-color: rgb(0,0,128);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <a href="#">Home</a>
 <a href="#">Test</a>
 <a href="#" class="dropdown">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="http://www.cnn.com">cnn</a>
   <a href="http://www.bbc.com">bbc</a>
  
  </div>
 <a href="#">About</a>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should get you started:

https://jsfiddle.net/kezpw1e7/

I modified some of the CSS and HTML. The dropdown works now, you'll just need to adjust the widths and some of the styling.

```
<style>
    body{
        margin: 0px;}

.nav
{
  width:100%;

}
     div {
        display: inline-block;
        /*width:25%;*/
        padding: 14px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;}
.dropdown
{
  position:relative;

}
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
        color: white;
        min-height: 50px;
        /*width: 25%;*/
    top:53px;
    left:0px;}

    .dropdown-content a {
        display: block;
        color:white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;}

    div.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
        display: block;}

    body > div:hover, .dropdown-content div:hover{
        background-color: rgb(0,0,128);}
</style>



<div class="nav">


  <div href="#">Home</div>
    <div href="#">Test</div>
    <div href="#" class="dropdown">News
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="http://www.cnn.com">cnn</a>
            <a href="http://www.bbc.com">bbc</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div href="#">About</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A link can not be inside a link. ([Link inside a div link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437785/link-inside-a-div-link))

When you try to do this, the browser takes out the inside link.

Try to enclose the News link in a different HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

.dropdown-content isn't a child of .dropdown so the css is never applied.

Try something like this

```
<div class="dropdown">News
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="http://www.cnn.com">cnn</a>
        <a href="http://www.bbc.com">bbc</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And change your css accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps

https://jsfiddle.net/usxk48d7/2/

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Test</a>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body a {
        display: inline-block;
        width:25%;
        padding: 14px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
            width:25%;
        padding: 14px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change the nesting. Since you cannot use a tag into an another one you must use a div for class dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#0">News</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#0">cnn</a>
            <a href="#0">bbc</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And you should trigger the hover event while hooking your dropdown-content class:

```
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Since your dropdown-content positioned absolute, you should reposition from top and left values of your div. Add this to the dropdown-content class:

```
    left: 60%;
    top: 55px;
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gp011zjp/

Although i do not recommend your approach. You can use better techniques for you dropdown menu.