# CSS3 switch inside clickable element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following html:

```
<li class="list-group-item li-tab-1">
    <div class="list-group-item-desc" data-target="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">
        <strong>1</strong>
        <div class="small m-t-xs">
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="tab-1-enabled" /> <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="tab-1-enabled"> <span
                class="onoffswitch-inner"></span> <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is a Bootstrap tab. `.onoffswitch` is a CSS3 switch.

**I'm trying to make the entire `<li>` clickable to show `#tab-1` as the tab content.** I can do this by defining a `<div>` with the `data-target` and `data-toggle` attributes. This works - when I click the div the tab shows.

However, embedded inside the `<li>` is a CSS3 switch. **I want that to work independently of the clickable div.**

This is similar to [Links inside of larger clickable areas (CSS Only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417272/links-inside-of-larger-clickable-areas-css-only), except the nested clickable elements are CSS3 switches instead of anchors.

Using the CSS3 switch outside the anchor works fine.

I tried making the actual hidden checkbox visible, removing the CSS3 styling, and clicking that. That *does* work, so is this related to CSS3?

I wondered if this is related to propogation - the trouble is that if I set an event listener for `control.select` or `change` I get no events - just the div click event.

Comment: [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) might solve your problem. You'll want to stop the propagation after the input it toggled so that the event doesn't continue on to the link. (That's if I understood you correctly)

Comment: When the CSS3 switch is shown, the event to click the checkbox doesn't appear to occur at all, only when the CSS3 pretty bits are stripped out and the <input> is shown does that work... I'll add a clarification.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. *The element `input` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element.*

Comment: I guess that's the problem.

Comment: I've now found that it won't work inside anything clickable, so I'm going to rewrite the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was propogation that was the problem (thanks @TW80000).

```
$(".list-group-item-desc").click(function(ev) {
    var isSwitchClick = $('.onoffswitch').has($(ev.target)).length > 0;
    if(isSwitchClick) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

That checks whether the click was inside the switch, and if so stops propogation.

In reality I have since moved the Bootstrap tab attrributes into the `<li>` but I think either approach should work to avoid swallowing the event.